# Skipping Turns (4/5 code complete, just need a bit of strategy help)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, int, java.util.scanner

I have a slight problem. The directions for the overarching problem are as follows:

- The game board has 31 cells.  The first one is labeled START, the last cell END, and the remaining cells are numbered 1 through 29.
- There are three players, A, B, and C.  The game starts with all players on the START cell.  Player A always goes first, then B, then C, then A, and so on.  The game ends when a player reaches the END cell or beyond.
- Each move consists of rolling an 8-sided die and moving that many cells forward.  However, if the die shows a 4, move backwards that many cells (but don't go before START!); if the die shows a 6, the player doesn't move at all and forfeits the next turn.  If a player lands on a cell occupied by the other player, the player that was on the cell jumps immediately to START.

Input:  The rolls of the 8-sided die for five games.  Each game consists of positive integers representing the rolls, terminated by a 0.  The first number is for player A, then B, then C, then A, and so on.  Each game ends as described above or when the 0 is read.

Output:  For each game, print the final position of the players A, B, and C.  The position of all three players must be correct to receive credit for each output; there is no partial credit.

So, before I start explaining the problem, I have 80% of the code complete. In no way am I looking for someone to do my work, I'm just looking for someone that could possibly explain to me a strategy to use for the following part of the problem.

I have completed the code fully for the movement part of the lab, such as all the dice cases from 1 to 8 excluding 6. Now, my problem is that I do not quite know how to make the program skip a players turn AND next turn if the dice is rolled to be a 6. In other words, how do I fulfill the "skip turn and forfeit next turn" requirement? The code I have so far (only works for inputs without the number 6) is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class seniorLab{
    static String input;
    static double parsedInput;
    static int i = 0;
    static int count = 1;
    static int positionA;
    static int positionB;
    static int positionC;
    static int valueOfRoll;
    static boolean aAtEnd;
    static boolean bAtEnd;
    static boolean cAtEnd;

    public seniorLab(){
    }

    static void labLoop(){
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            if (input.charAt(i) != '0'){
                if (i % 3 == 0){
                    valueOfRoll = charToNum(input.charAt(i));
                    positionA += valueOfRoll;
                    if (positionA == positionB){
                        positionB = 0;
                    } 
                    if (positionA == positionC){
                        positionC = 0;
                    }
                     if (positionA >= 31){
                        aAtEnd = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (i % 3 == 1){
                    valueOfRoll = charToNum(input.charAt(i));
                    positionB += valueOfRoll;
                    if (positionB == positionA){
                        positionA = 0;
                    } 
                    if (positionB == positionC){
                        positionC = 0;
                    }
                    if (positionB >= 31){
                        bAtEnd = true;;
                        break;
                    }
                 } else if (i % 3 == 2){
                   valueOfRoll = charToNum(input.charAt(i));
                    positionC += valueOfRoll;
                    if (positionC == positionA){
                         positionA = 0;
                    }
                    if (positionC == positionB){
                        positionB = 0;
                    }
                    if (positionC >= 31){
                        cAtEnd = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (input.charAt(i) == '0'){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Output #" + count + ":  ");
        System.out.print("A-" + positionA + ", B-" + positionB + ", C-" + positionC);
    }

    static int charToNum(char ch){
        switch (ch) {
            case '1': return 1;
            case '2': return 2;
            case '3': return 3;
            case '4': return -4;
            case '5': return 5;
            case '7': return 7;
            case '8': return 8;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Line #" + count + ":  ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        input = input.replaceAll("[,]", "");
        seniorLab sL = new seniorLab();
        sL.labLoop();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So basically, it sounds like you've got a position value for each player, but no notion of turns other than that loop. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Yes, I am able to track positions properly (as in, all test cases that do not include any 6's in them work perfectly) but right now I am relying completely on the position of the numbers in the string to calculate who's turn it is. For example, the position of the first character, when modulo'ed by 3, is 0, and for the second character, the modulus by 3 is 1, and for the third character the modulus by 3 is 2. Therefore, player A will move when the modulus i 0, player B when it is 1, and player C when it is 2. I don't know ho w to analyze who has skipped which turn.

Comment: Yeah, so looks like you'll have to do something a little different with determining turns. I'll let you give it a few tries.

Comment: At first I was thinking of using 3 booleans, skipA, skipB, and skipC, to determine who's turn it was, but that ended up failing. Then I tried to use a for loop that just continuously ran three methods (moveA, moveB, and moveC) all which accepted booleans in their parameters and only ran if the skipX boolean that corresponded to them was false. This also failed because I would need to increment the position of myself on the string. Kinda ran out of ideas after that.

Comment: What went wrong with the first approach?

Comment: The problem was that I would need to know when to set it to false (it boggled my brain), and how to run all three of the methods till I hit the end of the input string of numbers. I couldn't loop it because many times, the input string would not be completely divisible by 3 (for each player), meaning that sometimes C would move last but sometimes B would move last and the same case with A.

Comment: For example, this input string: 3,7,2,6,5,3,2,4,7,8,5,4,8,2,0 

A would move 3, B to 7, and C to 2. Then A would roll a 6 (skipA set to true) and B would move 5, C would move 3. Then A (because you rolled a 6 and skipA is true) would lose its turn, so B would move 2, and C would move 4. The problem here is how to make A, B, and C continuously do this, and then how and WHEN to set skipA back to false so A can continue after it has been skipped.

Comment: Well, how long are they skipped? If it's only one turn, then in your check, in the "true" case you can just set it back to false and not do the roll.

Comment: By "in your check", are you suggesting that I should have a method that checks my booleans to see whether they are false? Could you put this in semi-code for me?

Comment: It sounds like since you have to potentially skip more than one turn that a simple boolean might not be the best way to track that.  Can you think of something that would allow you to assign an arbitrary number of turns to skip instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By request, I'm outlining what I mentioned in comments in semi-code. Posting as an answer since this *does* address the issue.

I said earlier in the comments that you should try something different with respect to the turns. One thing that you can do is to put the players in a queue. Then, your game can go something like this

```
set all positions to 0
set all skip booleans to false
put the three players in the queue in order
for each character in the game string
    while the skip variable for the guy in front is true
        set it to false
        move the guy to the back of the line, leaving a new person in front

    // note that we only reach here if the person in front isn't getting
    // skipped this time. thus, the character corresponds to *his* move

    set the roll to the character that we're at right now
    if the roll is 6
        set skip value for that player to be true
    else
        calculate and modify that player's position as normal
    move player to back of queue
```

Here are some of the points with this approach:

1. Now, we're only changing up position if this isn't the "next turn" forfeited previously or the turn you lost by rolling a 6 this turn.
2. The `while the skip variable for the guy in front is true` part can get messy depending on how other things are implemented. Since this is your program, I'll let you weigh the pros and cons of possible approaches.
3. Instead of a queue, you *could* use an `int` as a variable to denote who's turn it is (using for example: 0 for A, 1 for B, 2 for C) and just remember to cycle through 0-1-2 where you'd otherwise be rotating players in the queue.

---

Disclaimer: I'm not saying this is the best approach to solving the problem. But, it can at least give you ideas and let you develop a working solution on your own.

Comment: Hi. I put this all into regular code, and it doesn't work and I know why:

I need to forfeit the current AND the next turn. In this case, should I set an integer to the amount of skips? So a switch would return skipA = 2, and when skipA becomes 0 then A would start running again

Comment: Sounds like a plan. My answer was intended to guide you in the right direction, not to be a catch-all. It sounds like you're thinking of an interesting idea, why not give it a try?